# Como colocar "Margen" por código en Android Studio y como poder cambiar el color de texto de los elementos de un spinner

Tags: android

estoy trabajando con tablelayout y tablerow, estoy usando esto para los tablerow, lo que me permite darle espacios (padding).

```
TextView text = new TextView(getApplicationContext());
text.setPadding(10,10,10,10);
```

quisiera saber si puedo hacerlo pero con los margenes, algo como `setMargin` pero no es así, probablemente esté de otra forma.

Otra cosa que tambíen es el como darle color a los elementos(textos) de un Spinner, porque me salen todos blancos y uso esto para llenar mi Spinner

```
List<Criterios> list = new ArrayList<Criterios>();
Spinner spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner);
for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++){
    JSONObject value = response.getJSONObject(i);
    list.add(new Criterios(value.getString("distrito"),value.getString("ubigeo")));}
final ArrayAdapter<Criterios> adap = new ArrayAdapter<Criterios>(getApplicationContext(),android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,list);
adap.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
spinner.setAdapter(adap);
```

Esos `value.getString()` son datos que estoy consumiendo de un servicio.

Y por último sería esto.

```
datoSolo.setText(value2.getString(iter2.next()).toUpperCase() + " " +
value2.getString(iter2.next()).toUpperCase() +"\n" + 
value2.getString(iter2.next()).toUpperCase());
```

Dudo que se pueda, pero por si acaso lo consulto, al concatenar todo estoy, hay la posibilidad de que pueda pintar de un color distinto solo de esos valores concatenados? algo como `valor1.getText()+""+valor2.getText()+""+valor3.getText().setTextColor(Color.BLUE)` claramente esto ultimo es referencial.

Comment: Angel, acostumbra no combinar varias preguntas en una, estas preguntando sobre margen a elementos de Tablelayout pero también sobre como personalizar elementos un Spinner. Si las separas tendrás mejores respuestas. De cualquier forma yo te ayudo.

Comment: Tienes razón, lo haré así a próxima vez, descuida.

Answer (score 0):

#### Aplicar margen a elementos en TableLayout.

En este caso puedes agregar un estilo dentro de `/values/styles.xml` donde definas los margenes deseados y su tamaño.

```
<style name="TableLayoutStyle">
    <item name="android:layout_marginTop">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginBottom">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">10dp</item>
    <item name="android:layout_marginRight">10dp</item>
</style>
```

Como ejemplo este layout:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

al aplicar el estilo en cada elemento mediante:

```
style="@style/TableLayoutStyle"
```

Ejemplo:

```
 <Button
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_span="1"
        android:text="Btn1"
        style="@style/TableLayoutStyle"/>
```

Se obtendrá el margen deseado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

#### Cambiar el color de texto y fondo en elementos de un spinner.

Para cambiar el color de los textos en un Spinner es necesario un Adapter personalizado, revisa este ejemplo, dentro del método `getView()` puedes cambiar el color del texto o del fondo de cada elemento.

```
@Override
public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent){
    LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
    view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
    TextView txv=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
    if(pos==0) { //Primer elemento color Azul #39399F
        txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#39399F"));
        txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); //Texto color Blanco
    }else { //Otros elementos ...
        txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF9DC"));
        txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#39399F")); //Texto color Azul
    }
    txv.setText(values.get(pos));
    return view;
}
```

Codigo de `Adapter` personalizado para `Spinner`.

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.util.List;

/**
 * Created by jorgesys 
 */
class SpinnerAdapter extends BaseAdapter {       
    List<String> values;
    Context context;
        
    public SpinnerAdapter(Context context, List<String> values){
        this.context = context;
        this.values = values;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount(){
        return values.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position){
        return values.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position){
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int pos, View view, ViewGroup parent){
        LayoutInflater inflater=LayoutInflater.from(context);
        view=inflater.inflate(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, null);
        TextView txv=(TextView)view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
        if(pos==0) { //Primer elemento color Azul #39399F
            txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#39399F"));
            txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FFFFFF")); //Texto color Blanco
        }else { //Otros elementos ...
            txv.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#FEF9DC"));
            txv.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#39399F")); //Texto color Azul
        }
        txv.setText(values.get(pos));
        return view;
    }

}
```

Para usar este Adapter, simplemente configuralo a tu Spinner:

```
   spinner.setAdapter(new SpinnerAdapter(getApplicationContext(), listadeDatos));
```

para obtener algo similar a:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: voy a probar lo de los spinner, ya que lo de margen ya lo solucioné mediante un "TableRow.Layoutparams" , Gracias @Jorgesys

Comment: Excelente @AngelCayhualla , si tienes duda me comentas, saludos!